# Using JQuery, how can enforce a resizable div to form-fit its child controls?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

The attached image has some info on how I'd like this resizable div to behave. 
[image: Resizable div behavior]

Basically, I'd like the div to be able to set the controls vertically or horizontally.

That said, say I have dynamically generated set of controls in a div, in this case:

```
<style type="text/css">
    button { width: 100px; }
    input { width: 100px; }    
</style>
<div id="block">
    <div id="content">
        <button id="btn1">Button One</button>
        <button id="btn2">Button Two</button>
        <input id="txb1"></input>
        <button id="btn3">Button Three</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

but it can be any number of buttons, textboxes, comboboxes, etc.

Here's what I have for JQuery thus far in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bladetrick/40avq57z/)

If you play with the fiddle, you'll see that the div doesn't conform to its children when resizing height-wise.

Its not working how i'd like it to and was hoping for some help/insight.  Thank you.

Comment: I need a clarification. In the live example, I'm able to resize the red section as I like. The content resizes accordingly, so what's the problem?

Comment: Apologies.  If you look at the image at #4, you'll see that the red div in the example can stretch out past the height of children controls.  I don't want extra red space.  i hope that helps.  Edit: I guess I want it to be like tight stretchy pants.  If i gain weight, the pants expand.  but if i lose a ton of weight, it still clings to me.  The pants don't become baggy. hehe.

Comment: Have your tried setting the `maxHeight` option?

Comment: Suggest `maxhi = numberOfControls * controlheight + padding;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet attempts to hug the height of the child-divs in whichever config they appear, a minimum width is set, and there's a function to calculate the max width (this function has been commented out though because with it on it effectively locks the resizability -which I'm not sure you want, but you can uncomment to see).

Note that the hidden button isn't the same way as simulating new content as the maxheight function looks for the height of the last child-div and if this has `display:none` then it assumes the bottom of the last child-div is zero. So the 'display' button has been adapted to append new buttons.

```js
var block = $("#block");
var content = $("#divContent")
var cons = content.children().length * 20;
var numberOfControls = content.children().length;
var controlheight = 20;
var padding = 5;
var totalwidth = 0;
var totalheight = 0;
var minwid = 0;
var maxwid = 0;
var minhi = 0;
var maxhi = 0;
var arrwid = [];

block.ready(function(e) {
  //--- initialize values
  totalwidth = 0;

  //--- Find the sum of lengths of controls to set the maximum width
  maxwid = getMaxWidth() + padding;

  //--- Find the control with the longest length for minimum width
  minwid = getMinWidth() + padding;

  //--- Find number of controls to set the height
  maxhi = getMaxHeight();

  //--- Find minHeight
  minhi = controlheight;
});

block.draggable();

function res() {
  block.resizable({
    maxWidth: maxwid,
    minWidth: minwid,
    maxHeight: maxhi,
    minHeight: minhi,
    resize: function(e) {


      block.height(getMaxHeight());
      //block.width(totalwidth);

      //content.width(totalwidth + 400);
      //alert(totalwidth);
    }
  });
}
$(window).load(function() {
  res(); // defined for later resetting
});

function getMaxWidth() {
  content.children().each(function(i, val) {
    totalwidth = totalwidth + $("#" + val.id).width() + padding;
  });
  return totalwidth;
}

/*
function getMaxWidth() {
    var tempWidth = [];
    content.children().each(function(i, val){
        tempWidth.push($(this).outerWidth());          
    });
    totalwidth = Math.max.apply(null, tempWidth);
    return totalwidth;
}  // this function will get you the maximum current width, but combined with maxheight will effectively lock your resizer.
*/

function getMinWidth() {
  var arrwid1 = [];
  content.children().each(function(i, val) {
    arrwid1.push($(this).width());
  });
  minwid = Number(Math.max.apply(null, arrwid1)) + padding;
  $('#w').text('minwidth =' + minwid);
  return minwid;
}

function getMaxHeight() {
  var dcon = $('#divContent').children().last(),
    totalwidth = dcon.position().top + dcon.height();
  $('#h').text('height =' + totalwidth);
  return totalwidth;
}

function getMinHeight() {
  return controlheight; //--- Height of a single control.
}

function recalculateDimensions() {
  numberOfControls = content.children().length;
  maxwid = getMaxWidth();
  minwid = getMinWidth();
  maxhi = getMaxHeight();
  minhi = getMinHeight();
}

$('#btnDisplayBTN').click(function() {
  $('#divContent').append('<button class="btnNewBTN">new button!</button>');
  recalculateDimensions();
  res();
});


$('#btnGetHeight').click(function btnGetHeight_Click() {
  alert((numberOfControls + padding) * controlheight);
});
```

```css
#block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px
}
#btnDisplayBTN {
  width: 100px;
}
#btnGetHeight {
  width: 100px;
}
.btnNewBTN {
  width: 100px;
}
#divContent {} div {
  width: 100%;
}
#monitor {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="block">
  <div id="divContent">
    <button id="btnDisplayBTN">Display</button>
    <button id="btnGetHeight" click="btnGetHeight_Click()">Total Height</button>
    <input id="txb" />
  </div>
</div>

<div id='monitor'>
  <div id='h'></div>
  <div id='w'></div>
</div>
```